# How do I update a Label when a TextBox value changes?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to update a label when entering values into a textBox?

The user can enter their level into a text box, which will then tell them what their multiplier is for that level. At the moment, when the user enters a number into the level field, the multiplier doesn't update until I click into the dropdown menu and reselect the option that I was on before.

For example; if the user enters 50 for their level, then the multiplier will be 1. If they enter >= 92, then the multiplier will show 2. But it doesn't update as a value is being entered into the text box.

Currently, for each object I've placed them in a Switch Case so it's easier to manage.

```
        private void Level_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RuneMultiplier.Refresh();
        }
```

`level` is the textBox that the user is able to put their level in, which should then update the multiplier label.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using Winforms.

Comment: You can code the TextChanged event to update the dropdown

Comment: The dropdown menu doesn't need updating as that stays the same. I need the Multiplier Label to update when a user enters a value into the Level textBox/ It does work with what I've got already, but the label doesn't update on the fly. It'll only update when I reselect the option from the dropdown.

Comment: When why not use the TextChanged event to update the Multiplier Label?

Comment: I've put in `Multiplier.Update();` but the same result.

Comment: @George_H We have no context as to where you're calling that method. You'd have to show us in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, why don't you make it a bit simple? Something like this ( with your example ):

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(textBox3.Text == "50")
   {
       label1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 1).ToString();
   }else if(int.Parse(textBox3.Text) >= 92)
   {
        label1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 2).ToString(); 
   }
   else
   {
        //this is not a number, some error message idk..
   }       
}
```

Everytime you entered something in textbox it will update your label or throwing some error depending on your if conditions..

**EDIT**

Something like this:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
switch (int.Parse(textBox3.Text))
{
    case 50:
        label1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 1).ToString();
    break;
    case int number when number >= 92:
        label1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 2).ToString();
    break;
    case int number2 when number2 < 50:
        label1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 0).ToString();
    break;
    default:
        //not a number
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems logcial, the only issue I see with this, is that there is more than one object that has a multiplier with different levels depending on that object. At the moment, every object has been placed into a switch case to make it easier to manage.

Comment: So you just have to move your switch case to inside of the textBox3_textChanged (on my answer, for example). I'll build another example.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what I've done wrong now... your example has made it clear. Thanks a lot! The switch statement was placed in the code for the ComboBox, so it would only update, if another option was selected.

Answer (score -1):

There are differnt approches to do that
Have a look at the events available on your textbox.
For example you can use OnLeave, etc.

A better way is to get notified by the "INotifyChanged" approach which is a fundamental better way to do that from the point of design.

Hopefully this helps you to solve your issue.